# Samsung Galaxy A70 Homescreen

Tags: samsung

Home screen items added to home screen like websites through Chrome Browser have all disappeared.

How do I get these items back on my home screens?

Thank you.

Comment: You have to add them back manually.  Did you change the home screen app ?

Comment: Links you have created via Chrome browser are bout to the Chrome app and it's app data. To my experience the links disappear if you clear app data of Chrome via Android settings (not from within Chrome).

Comment: Hello Rohit,  Thanks for your reply.  Add them back manually from where? The items are completely gone.  I did not change the home screen app.  I worry it may be related to going over capacity for memory.  What are all the steps I can test to troubleshoot the different scenarios?  Thank you kindly.

Comment: Hello Robert, Thank you for your reply. I didn't clear appvdata of Chrome via Android settings.  I just kept adding to the home screen.  Then I noticed my last items added were going onto the screens but all the others were gone.  Thank you.

Comment: Hello Robert,  Are you saying I still have all the items in the app data of Chrome?  If so, how do I access this data and put it back on my home screens as it was before?  Your help and time is very much appreciated.  Thank you.